# Woocommerce got Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method WooCommerce::get_image_size()

Tags: woocommerce, woocommerce-theming

I have an old theme and I think it is not compatible with the new version of woocommerce anymore. my website is showing error

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method
>   WooCommerce::get_image_size() in
>   /home3/lohasfarms/public_html/adohrmilkcream.com/wp-content/themes/AdohrMilkCream/woocommerce/single-product/product-thumbnails.php:16
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /home3/lohasfarms/public_html/adohrmilkcream.com/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-core-functions.php(211):
>   include() #1
>   /home3/lohasfarms/public_html/adohrmilkcream.com/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-template-functions.php(1053): wc_get_template('single-product/...') #2
>   /home3/lohasfarms/public_html/adohrmilkcream.com/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(286):
>   woocommerce_show_product_thumbnails('') #3
>   /home3/lohasfarms/public_html/adohrmilkcream.com/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(310):
>   WP_Hook->apply_filters('', Array) #4
>   /home3/lohasfarms/public_html/adohrmilkcream.com/wp-includes/plugin.php(453):
>   WP_Hook->do_action(Array) #5
>   /home3/lohasfarms/public_html/adohrmilkcream.com/wp-content/themes/AdohrMilkCream/woocommerce/single-product/product-image.php(36):
>   do_action('woocom in
>   /home3/lohasfarms/public_html/adohrmilkcream.com/wp-content/themes/AdohrMilkCream/woocommerce/single-product/product-thumbnails.php
>   on line 16

Could you help to find out what should I do for this issue?

This is my code for /public_html/adohrmilkcream.com/wp-content/themes/AdohrMilkCream/woocommerce/single-product/product-thumbnails

```
 <?php
/**
 * Single Product Image
 */

global $post, $woocommerce, $product;

// if less than 2.0
if ( version_compare( WOOCOMMERCE_VERSION, '2.0', '<' ) ) { 
    //$image_width = get_option( 'woocommerce_single_image_width' );
    //$image_height = get_option( 'woocommerce_single_image_height' );
} else {            
    $image_sizes = $woocommerce->get_image_size( 'shop_single' );
    $image_width = $image_sizes['width'];
    $image_height = $image_sizes['height'];
}

?>
<div class="imagecol images">
    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) : ?>

        <a data-rel="prettyPhoto[<?php echo $post->ID; ?>]" href="<?php echo sp_get_image($post->ID); ?>" class="zoom thickbox preview_link" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" data-id="<?php echo $post->ID; ?>" onclick="return false;">
        <img width="<?php echo $image_width; ?>" height="<?php echo $image_height; ?>" class="product_image attachment-shop_single wp-post-image" alt="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" src="<?php echo sp_timthumb_format('single_main', sp_get_image($post->ID), $image_width, $image_height); ?>" />
        </a>

    <?php else : ?>

        <a data-rel="prettyPhoto[<?php echo $post->ID; ?>]" class="zoom thickbox preview_link" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/no-product-image.jpg" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" data-id="<?php echo $post->ID; ?>" onclick="return false;">
        <img class="no-image" alt="No Image" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" src="<?php echo sp_timthumb_format('single_main', get_template_directory_uri().'/images/no-product-image.jpg', $image_width, $image_height); ?>" width="<?php echo $image_width; ?>" height="<?php echo $image_height; ?>" />
        </a>

    <?php endif; ?>            
  <?php 
      global $main_image_height; 
      $main_image_height = $image_height;   
      do_action('woocommerce_product_thumbnails');
  ?>
</div><!--close imagecol-->
```

Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

I found out a temporary solution

Just follow the path of error and comment the code like this one

```
// if less than 2.0
if ( version_compare( WOOCOMMERCE_VERSION, '2.0', '<' ) ) { 
    $image_width = get_option( 'woocommerce_single_image_width' );
    $image_height = get_option( 'woocommerce_single_image_height' );
} else {            
    //$image_sizes = $woocommerce->get_image_size( 'shop_single' );
    //$image_width = $image_sizes['width'];
    //$image_height = $image_sizes['height'];
}
```

Then the woocommerce can run
Hope this will help for whom get the same error